# Linq Search Date

Tags: c#, linq

how do I used date on searching using Linq. I think I'm missing something on the declaration

```
string searchName = Request.Form["PersonName"];
DateTime searchDateFrom = Request.Form["ReceivedDateFrom"];
DateTime searchDateTo = Request.Form["ReceivedDateTo"];

var Results = (from va in _db.myTable
       where ((va.PersonName.Contains(searchName)
               && (va.ApplicationReceivedDate > searchDateFrom 
                   && va.ApplicationReceivedDate < searchDateTo)
               select va).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HttpRequest.Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx) is a [NameValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx), where you can get strings in it by int/string indexer. That is, `Request.Form["ReceivedDateFrom"]` returns a string, you can't assign it to a variable whose type is `DateTime` without any convert. You can try [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) method to convert the string to a `DateTime`. But if you can't guarantee the string has a correct format, you can use a [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a typo, but you need to cast *searchDateFrom* / *searchDateTo* to a DateTime and you have two extra open brackets in your linq statement

Answer (score 0):

This is when I setup a unit test to see what's going on.

Check your brackets and casting from string to datetime:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        List<myTable> myTables = new List<myTable>();
        for (int month = 1; month < 10; month++)
        {
            for (int day = 1; day < 20; day++)
            {
                myTables.Add(new myTable { PersonName = "Person " + month.ToString() + " " + day.ToString(), ApplicationReceivedDate = new DateTime(2011, month, day) });
            }
        }

        string searchName = "Person";
        DateTime searchDateFrom = Convert.ToDateTime("2011-01-02");
        DateTime searchDateTo = Convert.ToDateTime("2011-01-03");

        var Results = (from va in myTables
                       where va.PersonName.Contains(searchName)
                               && va.ApplicationReceivedDate >= searchDateFrom
                                   && va.ApplicationReceivedDate < searchDateTo
                       select va);

        Assert.AreEqual(Results.Count(), 1);
    }

    public class myTable
    {
        public string PersonName { get; set; }
        public DateTime ApplicationReceivedDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Also check the search from & to.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also recommand using a cleaner indentation, it's easier to follow and count the brackets and stuff.

```
string searchName = Request.Form["PersonName"];
DateTime searchDateFrom = Request.Form["ReceivedDateFrom"];
DateTime searchDateTo = Request.Form["ReceivedDateTo"];

var Results = (from va in _db.myTable
              where va.PersonName.Contains(searchName)
              && (va.ApplicationReceivedDate > searchDateFrom 
              && va.ApplicationReceivedDate < searchDateTo)
              select va).ToList();
```